# Checking for a value inside jQuery cookie object

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm using [Jquery.cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/tree/v1.4.1) plugin but I can't seem to find the information i'm looking for.

I have the cookie object which contains keys and values for cookies that are set on the page.

Want I need to do is loop through the object and check to see if a value exists inside the object and if it does log it to the console.

```
$.cookie().each(function() {
  if (index == ratingsID) {
    console.log(index)
  }
});
```

With the above code I get an error that says undefined is not a function.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if($.cookie("MyCookie") != null){
    cookie = JSON.parse($.cookie("MyCookie"));
    cookie.forEach(function(elem){
        console.log(elem);
    });
}
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I tried this but having no luck, the issue may be in my original code above 'ratingsID' is a string variable, the value of this variable is what I'm checking for in the cookie, if the ratingID matches a key in the object, log that key to the console.

Comment: When you save your string in cookie, use JSON.stringify(MyArray)